# Fonts not supported in Oreo

Tags: android, fonts, android-8.0-oreo

I have an app in which I have a font named "Crilee" which works perfect in other devices but not in Oreo version in android. I have used `settypeface()` for setting the fonts. Can I know the reason why some of the fonts are not supported in Oreo version and also in some devices?

Comment: where do you have added ttf font file?

Comment: inside  assets => fonts=> folder

Answer (score 2):

**Android 8.0 (API level 26)** introduces a new feature, [Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml), which lets you use fonts as resources.

Add your font files in the **font** folder under **res** directory.

[image]

Then, create a font family xml file under **font** folder.
Enclose each font file, style, and weight attribute in the `<font>` element as below example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />
<font
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />
</font-family>
```

**Using fonts in XML layouts**

In the layout XML file, set the `fontFamily` attribute to the font file you want to access.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"/>
```

**Using fonts programmatically**

To retrieve fonts programmatically, call the `getFont(int)` method and provide the resource identifier of the font you want to retrieve.

```
Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.myfont);
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

**Note:** To use the Fonts in XML feature on devices running **Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher**, [use the Support Library 26](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#using-support-lib).

Comment: can you please tell  how to use support library 26? because still it is not working in oreo .

Comment: check this link for [Using the support library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#using-support-lib)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced exactly the same problem and I fixed it uploading the ttf file to https://everythingfonts.com/font-face and using the generated ttf file by this website.
It magically worked. If any one knows more about the kind of conversion it does would be great to share.